# Script does not work while on login screen

Tags: linux, shell, security, webcam

I have coded the following shell script that takes pictures from the webcam while my laptop screen is not blanked out:

```
STATE0=$(xset -q | tail -1)
STATE1="  Monitor is On"


while true;
do
STATE0=$(xset -q | tail -1)

if [ "$STATE0" = "$STATE1" ]
then
  ts=`date +%s`
  streamer -f jpeg -o /home/user/securityPICS/screen$ts.jpeg

fi

done
```

This is because I work in an open office and someone has been trying to log in into my laptop at nights.
The script seems to work fine, but once I lock the screen of the computer and I'm in the login screen it stops working.

I wonder if anybody could advise about this. I have tried to run the script with ./scriptname, sudo ./scriptname, nohup ./scriptname ...

Regards,
Janus

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: The script does not take pictures while on the login screen, once I have locked my computer screen.